# iOS Load Image in UIWebView

Tags: ios, image, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

Desperately trying to figue out how to load a local image (saved in local xcode bundle) into the following HTML through a UIWebView. I have spent countless hours following other guides but nothing seems to work, all throw erros. Am trying to add a local image in the following NSString where I have written IMAGEGOESHERE -

```
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = _restaurant.title;

    [[self navigationController] setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];

    self.activityIndicatorView.hidden = NO;
    [self.activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

    [self loadImageInNewThread];


    NSString *webViewContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>* {font-family:   Helvetica}</style></head><body><center>%@ - %@<br><br><b>Restaurant:</b>%@</b><br>IMAGEGOESHERE<br></center></b></body></html>", _restaurant.openingTime,_restaurant.closingTime, _restaurant.name];

    [self.webView loadHTMLString:webViewContent baseURL:nil];
}
```

I hope you can help as its driving me mad!

Answer (score 2):

You need to reference first the path of your image:

```
 NSString *pathImg = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourimage" ofType:@"png"];
```

and then specify your path in your webViewContent along with the size of your image:

```
NSString* webViewContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"<html>"
                                   "<body>"
                                   "<img src=\"file://%@\" width=\"200\" height=\"500\"/>"
                                   "</body></html>", pathImg];
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I cant get this to work, where is the first line of code actually meant to sit/be placed, if I put it above NSString *webViewContent it throws an error?

Answer (score 0):

This code should work,
Just replace yourFile with the name of your PDF, and webView with the name of your webView.
Then Replace ofType to the extension of your image.

```
//PDF View
       //Creating a path pointing to a file.pdf
       NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourFile" ofType:@"pdf"];
       //Creating a URL which points towards our path
       NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
       //Creating a page request which will load our URL (Which points to our path)
       NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
       //Telling our webView to load our above request
       [webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *pathImg = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourimage" ofType:@"png"];
NSString* webViewContent = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"<html>"
                               "<body>"
                               "<img src=\"file://%@\" width=\"200\" height=\"500\"/>"
[webView loadHTMLString:webViewContent baseURL:nil];
```

You must add the last line with a base url of nil