# iOS WebView load html with local images

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

I need to load HTML with hundreds of xml and images with paths like : "vt0\0\0\1\0_0.jpg". Many images have same names.

XML files have strings like url="vtd/vt0/3/1/%v_%u.jpg"/>

I know bundle directory has no paths in it.
Is it possible to keep local paths without having to edit all those xml?

i tried to use this

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]]
```

and this

```
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURL]
```

but images got lost

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12093885/3733561 try this

Comment: This is for one image. I have 1 html, 10 xml files and 500+ small images. Images linked to xml, xml linked to html. In objc code i'm requesting just 1 file - html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for me : custom java script for parse xml, copy and rename all images like `file.toString().replace("/", "_");`

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to pack everything into a zip file and include it into the bundle. Then on first start of your app, to unpack-it into the sandbox preserving your desired hierarchy.

A nice side effect is that xcode will have to handle only one file:D